# How do you use the Unified Verb Index in Python?

Tags: nlp, corpus, tagged-corpus

I know that `nltk` contains the VerbNet corpus, however, the [Unified Verb Index](http://verbs.colorado.edu/verb-index/index.php) combines information from it and 3 other useful sources. Is there any way to use this corpus in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Through NLTK you can certainly access FrameNet, VerbNet and PropBank. I haven't done any work with the OntoNotes Sense Groupings.

Look at the below for an idea of how to get information out of these three resources. Each of them returns a list so you can grab list elements individually and examine them in however much detail you need.

```
from nltk.corpus import verbnet as vn
from nltk.corpus import framenet as fn
from nltk.corpus import propbank as pb

input = 'take'

vn_results = vn.classids(lemma=input)

if not vn_results:
    print input + ' not in verbnet.'
else:
    print 'verbnet:'
    print vn_results

fn_results = fn.frames_by_lemma(input)

if not fn_results:
    print input + ' not in framenet.'
else:
    print 'framenet:'
    print fn_results

pb_results = []
try:
    pb_results = pb.rolesets(input)
except ValueError:
    print input + ' not in propbank.'

if pb_results:
    print 'propbank:'
    print pb_results
```